# python glob and iglob when iterating over two directories

Tags: python, glob

When I try iterate over two directories, the first with a smaller number of files, the second with a larger number of files, I run into a problem:
I wanted to use iglob for the large number of files, but this doesn't work.

```
large_n_files = glob.iglob(pathtodir)
small_n_files = glob.iglob(pathtootherdir)

for s in small_n_files:
    for l in large_n_files:
        print(l,s)
```

yields (assuming e.g. small_n = 2, large_n = 3)

```
l1 s1
l2 s1
l3 s1
```

When I switch to `glob` for the large_n_files, I get the result that I want, i.e.

```
large_n_files = glob.glob(pathtodir)
small_n_files = glob.iglob(pathtootherdir)

for s in small_n_files:
    for l in large_n_files:
        print(l,s)
```

yields

```
l1 s1
l2 s1
l3 s1
l1 s2
l2 s2
l3 s2
```

Why is this so? (I guess I have to learn more about iterators...) If I want to use this for a really large number of files wouldn't glob be less efficient? How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do :

```
small_n_files = glob.iglob(pathtootherdir)
```

You get back in the iterator; this means you can iterate over it only once.

on the other hand when you do:

```
large_n_files = glob.glob(pathtodir)
```

then you create a list, which you can iterate multiple times. (it creates an iterator object for each loop of small_n_files). but you have the full list in memory.

if you don't want to hold the large_n_files in memory (as it's to big), you can use the following code:

```
small_n_files = glob.iglob(pathtootherdir)

    for s in small_n_files:
        for l in glob.iglob(pathtodir):
            print(l,s)
```

This way you never have the full list of pathtodir in memory.